# Why is redirecting stdout/stderr on android not working?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, stdout

I downloaded SDL 1.3 and tested it together with OpenGL ES on my android 2.2 device. It works fine but I don't get the outputs from the `printf` calls. I tried the commands below as mentioned at the [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd) but neither `DDMS` in Eclipse nor `adb logcat` reports the strings that the program writes using `printf`. I made sure to filter for the `stdout` tag.

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, this causes the Dalvik VM to create a thread that copies stdout/stderr to the log file.  You need to be root to stop/start the app framework.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188987/android-native-code-debugging/17199704#17199704 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is having a file `/data/local.prop`, containing just the line `log.redirect-stdio=true`. Maybe this works better? Also, note that stdout is buffered, so it could be that your output is still sitting in the buffer, waiting to be flushed. You can call `fflush` manually to check this.

Comment: adb push local.prop /data/local.prop does not work because of permissions. Do I have to root my device?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize that this would give you trouble on a device. It works fine on the emulator though. I know the emulator is a pain to use, especially with OpenGL, but maybe it's an option for incidental trouble shooting? According to a message by David Turner on the NDK group (see http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/msg/0d37b24df6df7cde ) the stop/setprop/start should be considered unsupported.

Comment: Does this work from C?  I see stderr output to logcat from java when I do this, but I don't see output from C calls to something like fprintf(stderr, "something").

Answer (score 2):

According to this [presentation](http://elinux.org/images/c/c9/Android-tips-and-tricks-2010-10.pdf), `log.redirect-stdio` is for Dalvik output, to redirect C/C++ output (such as `printf`), you must install busybox on the device and use its `xargs` utility like this:

```
myprogram | xargs log
```

This obviously works for code that gets called as a standalone executable. If it's only for debugging purposes, you can write a tiny program to call your library and call that from your application using `xargs`.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192749/capturing-stdout-stderr-with-ndk for a solution with pipes instead of busybox.