# What to do if manufacturer removed folders under /dev/log folder? [means No LogCat]

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I'm in trouble with my android device in which log folder under **/dev** is unreachable or maybe even does not exists.

```
$ pwd
pwd
/dev
$ cd log
cd log
cd: can't cd to log
$
```

So LogCat is out-of-service and I cannot view device's stdout or stderr logs in DDMS.

I googled a little bit and tried to find some information for about this problem:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#alternativebuffers

   **Viewing stdout and stderr** topic seemed to be useful but this thread says it is unsupported :

   [Why is redirecting stdout/stderr on android not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499202/why-is-redirecting-stdout-stderr-on-android-not-working)
2. Here is another one having the same problem:

   ["Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory/6993662#6993662)

I found a temporary solution to dump my logs in a file on device manually but as usual I cannot monitor system just my application logs.

Is there any solution you can suggest? Any way to redirect stdout and stderr logs to files,console etc.?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RunO NesrE - I finally found the solution to this.

There is a recent post on the xda-developers forum for a different Huawei phone with the same problem and it has a fix.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17774398&postcount=93

It worked a treat on my Huawei Sonic (U8650).

Answer (score 19):

**Solution:**

On call screen 
type *****#*****#2846579#*****#*

opens system management menu

Project menu -> background settings -> **Log setting**

Log level setting -> VERBOSE
Log switch -> LOG on

**Dump and Log** -> Checked all the boxes

Restart device.

Thats all.

Comment: This works, even *without* checking any box in *Dump and Log*.

Answer (score 3):

What device is this?  If it ships with Market, it must pass the CDD, and that includes having the development tools needed for app development which includes logcat support (though this just means the logcat command, technically the implementation could be different).  For such a device the manufacturer must supply an update to make it compatible.

If it is not a compatible device, all bets are off, and you will just need to get help from the manufacturers or any hackers who are working with the device.

Comment: It's a **Huawei u8650** produced for a local carrier with a different name.

Comment: Ugh. Doesn't surprise me. The first Huawei phone I tried, which I believe had the Market, had /dev/log/* but reading the files gave no output.