# Where I can find full documentation for android ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to have a full documentation for android ndk.

or a url that explains how to use android specific strings like jstring  and functions that will call android functions from c etc.

Comment: I didn't get a perfect one, that's why i am asking whether anyone has a good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean JNI, the means of Java/C interaction. Try http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

Comment: Thanks Seva. that was a good one. I will accept you answer in 10 minutes. One more question? Can we call an android function from C?

Comment: Sure. Read on up JNI, it's all there.

Comment: Seva : I have another doubt :- where I can find the printf output in ndk?

Comment: That's another file, not a part of JNI. #include <android/log.h>, then use __android_log_write() and __android_log_print() with arguments. It all goes to LogCat in Eclipse.

Comment: You can also set property "log.redirect-stdio=true", to redirect stdio/stderr to android logging facility. Read here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499202/why-is-redirecting-stdout-stderr-on-android-not-working It will require rooted device though.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder `android-ndk/docs` there are documentation that is connected with android-ndk.