# Android STDIO redirect does not work

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

The android system setting log.redirect-stdio does not seem to have any effect on ICS devices. This is a huge pain on the already painful C/C++ Native code debugging.

According to this link STDIO redirection is as simple as setting the system property log.redirect-stdio to true.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

This does work on pre-ICS devices but not on anything on or past ICS. Google = bug king!

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Did you find an answer to this - there seems to be conflicting information available: the link you show above implies it should work, whereas the link to the google groups discussion in  svdree's comment (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499202/why-is-redirecting-stdout-stderr-on-android-not-working) implies it does not. I have tried on a rooted and non-rooted 4.0 device with no success.