# How to redirect stdout to logcat from a shell script in a rooted device?

Tags: android, shell, stdout, logcat

I'm running a shell script in a rooted Android device, and I'm trying to debug it by tracing the stdout output generated by the shell script(either by the commands or by echo). Is it possible to do this by redirecting stdout to logcat?

Comment: If you can find the file that logcat is writing to, you can just use the command "command >> logcatfile"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is redirecting stdout/stderr on android not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499202/why-is-redirecting-stdout-stderr-on-android-not-working)

Answer (score 7):

Within your Android Shell script, use the following:

```
   log -p v -t "test"  "test script message"
```

You will then see your message within Androids Logcat:

> adb logcat | grep test

Usage:

```
log [-p priorityChar] [-t tag] message
    priorityChar should be one of:
        v,d,i,w,e
```

This works for me on `Droid 4.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stdio to logcat. This works for me, so that NDK C code printfs appear in logcat. [Redirect method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499202/why-is-redirecting-stdout-stderr-on-android-not-working)